# R include rows conditioned to other variables with `add_row`

Tags: r, rbind

I have a data.frame like `test`. It corresponds to information associated with a registry of firms. `year.entry` reflects the time period when a firm gets into the registry. `items` are elements that represent capacity and remain fixed throughout time. It may happen that the firm increases its capacity in a particular year. My aim is to present this information longitudinally.

For doing that I would ideally include rows for the years that are missing between 2010 and 2015. I have tried with this with `add_row()` from [`tibble`](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/08/29/tibble-1-2-0/) but I am having difficulties to make it work.

```
    > test %>% add_row(firm = firm, year.entry == (year.entry)+1, item = item, .before = row_number(year.entry) == n())

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'firm' not found
```

I wonder whether there is an easier way to solve this problem. The ideal data frame should look like this:

```
                      firm              year.entry  item
                     <chr>                  <chr> <int>
                       1 1-102642692       2010    15
                       2 1-102642692       2011    15
                       3 1-102642692       2012    15  
                       4 1-102642692       2013    15
                       5 1-102642692       2014    15
                       6 1-102642692       2015     8
```

`test` is given by:

```
test = data.frame(firm = c("1-102642692", "1-102642692"), year.entry = c(2010, 2015), item =c(15,8))
```

Comment: Your dput shows error `Error in structure(list(firm = c("1-102642692", "1-102642692"), year.entry = c("2010",  : 
  object 'firm' not found`

Comment: Edited. Thanks, akrun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add a dummy firm to the data to use later.

- First I make sure every firm has all the years of the period of interest with `complete`. That is why I entered a dummy firm.
- The missing years are added to the dataframe.
- Then I take the last observation carried forward with `na.locf`.
- When completed I remove the dummy firm.

---

```
comp <- data.frame(firm="test", year.entry= (2009:2016), item=0)

 test = data.frame(firm = c("1-102642692", "1-102642692"), year.entry = c(2010, 2015), item =c(15,8))

      library(zoo)

 rbind(test,comp) %>% 
   complete(firm,year.entry) %>% 
   arrange(firm, year.entry)%>%
   group_by(firm) %>%
   mutate(item = na.locf(item, na.rm=FALSE)) %>%
   filter(firm !="test")
```

result:

```
 firm              year.entry item
 <fctr>            <dbl>      <dbl>
 1-102642692       2009       NA
 1-102642692       2010       15
 1-102642692       2011       15
 1-102642692       2012       15
 1-102642692       2013       15
 1-102642692       2014       15
 1-102642692       2015        8
 1-102642692       2016        8
```

Comment: That´s very nice and response. Many thanks. You made me discover `na.locf`as well - which seems to be very useful.